# Creating a Menu in a circular layout

Tags: android, menu

trying to find out how to make a menu that is in a circular layout. I believe it is called a Pie Menu or Circular Menu. See screenshot from an app named Simple Habit on Android Studio. I have no idea how to get started.

I'm sure many other people also would like to know, help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: screenshot from Simple Habit]

Comment: Constraint Layout has circular positioning relative to a view. You can achieve this without using a custom library

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [this](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu)

Dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.szugyi:Android-CircleMenu:2.0.0'
```

Add to Activity/Fragment XML:

```
<com.szugyi.circlemenu.view.CircleLayout
    android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/selected_textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/menu_items" />
</com.szugyi.circlemenu.view.CircleLayout>
```

Add this to menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_speed"
    android:title="@string/speed"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_radius"
    android:title="@string/radius"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_isRotating"
    android:title="@string/is_rotating"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_firstChildPosition"
    android:title="@string/first_child_position"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

More details in [Sample App](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu/tree/master/sample).

If you are looking for a Lucky wheel, add [this library](https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel) as a module into your project.